# compile java classes maven exec plugin

Tags: maven

I have a maven project. I have a java class that reads a file and creates pojo's and this pojo is then used by the project.

I created a maven exec plugin to run the java class during the validate phase as I want the generated pojo's to be present when compiling happens.

But the problem is in the validate phase maven exec is not able to find the class that creates the pojo as it has not been compiled yet.

Is it possible to compile few classes in the validate phase of a maven project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. You will need to run the code generation in its own project to generate the code. The best thing is to create your own maven plugin for this code generation.

Comment: Thanks, If I make the pojo generation as another project, can I force maven to run the generation project first and then my actual project.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one project if you compile your codegenerator in the 'initialize' phase and then use it to generate the code in the 'generate-sources' phase.

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

But I would probably use two modules as bmargulies suggested: one project for your code generator and one for your code. Don't use the validate phase for this stuff, though; that's the wrong place for it.